# Trouble importing Cognito, "AmazonCognitoIdentity is not defined"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am a beginner at Node JS and trying to follow examples online and learning fairly well from AWS documentation. So far I am only using the web based lambda editor that AWS provides. Following code gives me trouble and states that, "errorMessage": "AmazonCognitoIdentity is not defined",

Could someone please advise how I can successfully start using Cognito using web editor only?

```js
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var CognitoUserPool = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool;



exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  console.log("Do something here...");
}
```

Comment: Try `aws.AmazonCognitoIdentity`

Comment: Thank you @FranciscoMateo, that did the work. Silly mistakes from the beginners! Such also helped me follow up the syntax of the API!

Answer (score 6):

Example to use `aws-sdk`

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const cognitoIdentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();

cognitoIdentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(params, function (err, data) 
     {
//handle error and data
      });
```

Comment: Ty sir! I ended up using the following,

var cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-18', region: 'us-east-2' });

Now I just need to attend to the documentation further to understand what CognitoIdentity vs CognitoIdentityServiceProvider does.